# A specific GWT DataGrid and Panels display in browser with height of 0. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have 3 `DataGrid` objects that are implemented exactly the same way. They are inserted into the same types of `Panel`, then they are displayed on a web page. Two of the `DataGrid`s display exactly as expected, but the third one doesn't. 
I want the third one to appear in a `DialogBox`. At first I thought it was an issue with the `DialogBox`, but if I remove `DataGrid` 3 and add `DataGrid` 2 then it works fine. I've been at this for far too many hours now and I've got no idea what the issue is. I've searched the CSS files looking for issues but I couldn't find any. 
Here are some screenshots:

[image: div]

The corresponding markup:

[image: div markup]

When you inspect the element you can see that the data is actually there, it's just not displaying:

[image: data markup]

And how that looks in the `DialogBox`:

[image: data]

What could I be doing wrong here?